# How to use useStyles and makeStyles from Material UI with Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I am trying to use Material UI in my Gatsby project but the syntax is completely different and I would like to understand what is happening in this scenario.

I am trying to pass useStyles to my header component and have tried a ton of different approaches and read gatsby and react docs but im hitting a wall.

I would greatly appreciate an explanation on the difference between

```
const {classes} = useStyles();
const {classes} = useStyles
```

as well as when the return() notation is required within a component

also do I need to pass useStyles into the function to begin with?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

const Header = ({ siteTitle }) => {
  const {classes} = useStyles

  return classes (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            {siteTitle}
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

Header.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.string,
}

Header.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: ``,
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question - `useStyles` is a function that returns an object. If you want to be able to use that object (and you want, this is the way to use it) - you need to call the function.

If you do `const {classes} = useStyles` - this makes no sense, because there is no `classes` entity inside your `useStyles` reference (which is a reference to a function).

Once you call the `useStyles` function and put it's value inside the `classes` const - you can use `classes.CLASS_NAME` (which eventually creates a generated classname with the style-values that you wrote, based on the `makeStyles` definition.

In your example - `classes.title` will create a new class (lets say that the name is `makeStyles-root-1`) with the value of `flex-grow: 1`.
If it would be a css file it will look like this:

```
.makeStyles-root-1 {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

And inside your react component you could use it like this:

```
<div className="makeStyles-root-1">...</div>
```

Instead - you have an easy reference to that specific styling inside your javascript code.

Regarding your code - it should look like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

const Header = ({ siteTitle }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            {siteTitle}
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

Header.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.string,
}

Header.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: ``,
}

export default Header
```